# Question about convert List of string to case class

Tags: scala

I have two types of List[String], List("1234:abcd") and List("1234:*"), I want to convert these list of string to "case class FeatureWhitelisting", "byName" means whitelisting has name ("abcd"), "ALL" means no name (" * ").

```
sealed trait myWhitelisting

    object myWhitelisting {
      case class ByName(name: String) extends myWhitelisting
      case object All extends myWhitelisting
  }

  case class FeatureWhitelisting(accountId: String, whitelisting: myWhitelisting)
```

right now I have this, what should be the second parameter? ]

```
list.map(acct => FeatureWhitelisting(acct.split(":")(0), ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use pattern matching:

```
List("1234:abcd", "1234:*")
  .map { str =>
    str.split(":") match {
      case Array(accountId, "*") => FeatureWhitelisting(accountId, All)
      case Array(accountId, name) => FeatureWhitelisting(accountId, ByName(name))
    }
  }
  .foreach(println(_))
```

Comment: Hi @User9123, the second list if List("1234 : * "), there's a *, in ur case it will go to  "case Array(accountId, name) => FeatureWhitelisting(accountId, ByName(name))"

Comment: @mcy, i fix my answer for "*"

Comment: Hi @User9123, whats the reason of using Array in pattern matching?

Comment: @mcy Because of split return Array, it's more readable and easy for code understanding

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not missing any nuance here, but would

```
list.map{acct => 
      val myVals = acct.split(":").padTo(2, "*")
      FeatureWhitelisting(myVals(0), myVals(1) match {
        case "*" => myWhitelisting.All
        case s => myWhitelisting.ByName(s)
      }
  )
}
```

do the job?

Comment: great example of using `padTo`, and I still suggest to add `trim` to `myVals(1)`.